# R integration issue: non-finite function value

Tags: r, integrate, weibull

I have been trying to integrate a weibull distribution from 0 to a given value, to estimate a failure rate based on a distribution model. all my attempts have been giving me the "non-finite function value" error
I have tried to use ifelse and sapply, and both have failed to solve the issue..

here is my code so far:

```
f <- function (y) ( (beta1/y) * ((y/alpha1)^beta1) * exp(-((y/alpha1)^beta1)) );
f1 <- function (y) sapply(y,f);
R = integrate( f1, 1e-10, 10 );
```

please let me know if I'm missing anything obvious..

Comment: Please format your question. At least using code-blocks (with 4 whitespace characters). That being said, Welcome on SO.

Comment: What are alpha1 and beta1?

Comment: alpha1 and beta1 are the parameters of my weibull distribution. They range from 1 to 7 from alpha, and 0.9 to 3 for beta. I'm actually calculating this integral for a range of different distributions, hence the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare beta1 and alpha1. Try this:

```
f <- function (y, alpha1, beta1) {
    (beta1/y) * ((y/alpha1)^beta1) * exp(-((y/alpha1)^beta1)) 
}
f1 <- function (y, alpha1, beta1) {
    sapply(y,f, alpha1, beta1)
}
R <- integrate(f1, 1e-10, 10, alpha1 = 1, beta1 = 0.9)
```

You can iterate through alpha1 and beta1 values.